# Updating excel sheet without overwriting using openpyxl :Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update sheet without overwriting the complete data but my code is creating a new sheet instead.

```
import csv
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\Data_Sj.csv')
ddf = df1[
    (df1['Sports'] == 'Football')
         ]
print(ddf)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\check\Checklist1.xlsx', engine= 'openpyxl')

book = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\check\Checklist1.xlsx')

writer.book = book
ddf.to_excel(r'C:\Users\name\Desktop\check\Checklist1.xlsx')

writer.save()
```

Comment: Are you able to share your code?

Comment: I just added above